# count characters textarea and change color counted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the simple code, it's works fine. This code counting characters in `textarea` and result show in div 0,1,2 etc. 
I would like obtain effect when result counted is < 100 font-color will be red and when counted result is > 100 change font-color on green.
How can i do it?

```js
function countChar1(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;

  $('#charNum').text(0 + len);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="opis_siebie" type="text" rows="6" cols="15" name="opis_siebie" onkeyup="countChar1(this)"></textarea><br />

<div id="charNum" ">0</div>
```

Comment: I posted in my title post, it's not visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you already have the length of the text, add an if statement and change the color accordingly

```js
function countChar1(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  var color;
  $('#charNum').text(0 + len);

  color = len < 100 ? 'red' : 'green';
  $('#charNum').css({
    'color': color
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="opis_siebie" type="text" rows="6" cols="15" name="opis_siebie" onkeyup="countChar1(this)"></textarea><br />
<div id="charNum" ">0</div>
```

Comment: thanks for fast help, but i want change color only number not text inside textarea

Comment: i edited the answer to style `$('#charNum')` instead of the text in the textarea