# How to make specific number of characters change color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a [Karuta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk5BM.png) web game.
In karuta, there are "kimariji", which are the minimum amount of "letters" needed to know which card to take. These counts will be stored in the API/JSON I've created, which get saved as a state and read from.

I'm looking to do this: (english example)

```
var kimarijiCount = 6
string = 'Elephant'
in this case, only 'Elepha' turns red.

var kimarijiCount = 2
string = 'Rhino'
in this case, only 'Rh' turns red.
```

How can I do this using javascript/react? I'm assuming my pseudocode would be:

```
//get string
//get count variable x
//set css for the first x chars to a different colour
```

This is how my code for creating the cards current looks, if it helps

```
    render() {      
if (this.props.displayType === "kanji") {
        return (
            <div id="CardContainer" className="cardContainer">
                {this.props.cards.slice(0, this.props.number).map((cards, index) => (
                    <div id="card" className="cardOuter" onClick={() => this.props.handleComp(index)}>
                        <div className="cardInner">
                            <p key={index}>{cards.back}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}

            </div>)
    }
```

Comment: I think pseudocode would be a bit more like: 1) Split string at index, 2) wrap each substring in span, 3) color each span the color desired.

Comment: Can you try and make a runnable snippet?  This illustrates how you can change the color with CSS based on the characters in a string.  http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/54EY4/6/  Just take the random part out and  you have almost everything that you need.  It even shows you hot to wrap the letters in a span.  Also, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654928/how-can-i-give-different-color-for-each-letter-in-a-text-field

Comment: i think this will help you check this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969868/count-characters-textarea-and-change-color-counted

Comment: I've got it working with a test of 3 with this code `<p  style={mystyle} key={index}>{cards.back.slice(0,3)}</p><p>{cards.back.slice(3, cards.back.length)}</p>`, but it only works if I change the page after the DOM has already been loaded. If I refresh the page, I just get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
' error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-snowflake-nomli?file=/src/App.js) that should work for the example you gave!

In short, you probably want to use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) on your kimariji:

```
// Slice the first `kimarjiCount` characters of kimarji and make them red
<span color={{ color: "red" }}>{kimarji?.slice(0, kimarjiCount)}</span>

// Append the rest of the kimarji
<span>{kimarji?.slice(kimarjiCount, kimarji.length)}</span>
```

This uses the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator to ensure that the `kimarji` variable exists before calling `slice` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've done this in an above comment and it works, but only if I edit the js after the page has already loaded. If I refresh the page I get the error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined'. How can I fix this?

Comment: I sounds like you might not be setting `cards.back` to an initial value (or it's being set to `undefined` after being rendered). An easy way to get around that it with the optional chaining operator which I've updated my answer with!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const`, `let`, or `var` for text_color, which helps you to customize and change color property.

```
// var kimarijiCount = 2
// var str = 'Rhino'

const text_color = { color: 'red' };

let res = str.substring(0, kimarijiCount);
let rest = str.substring(kimarijiCount, str.length);

<span style= { text_color }> { res } </span> { rest };
```

`kimarijiCount` must be limited to `str.length`